# different multisig address from the same public keys

Tags: multi-signature

When I use `bitcoin-cli -testnet` to generate a 2-of-3 address, the code:

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet createmultisig 2 '''
 [
   "03b91ff254ae3bb3861e4a6c16ab356d6c52ccfd2b58bedf0dda84657dfd9d9afc",
   "039f1475fb37d91ed65765c897acbdc37da3a7aba19f5b8ad5ff22a994e8350798", 
   "030ee8793fa2cb93f0cfd475b990cbaa48a28d83bd8f434348607368e52644febf"
 ]'''
```

the result is

```
"address": "2MzSwUwBc1xuNHwRotwrdFugLvju8VV9uPT",
```

But when I use `bitcoinjs-lib`, the code is:

```
var pubKeys = [
'03b91ff254ae3bb3861e4a6c16ab356d6c52ccfd2b58bedf0dda84657dfd9d9afc',
'039f1475fb37d91ed65765c897acbdc37da3a7aba19f5b8ad5ff22a994e8350798',
'030ee8793fa2cb93f0cfd475b990cbaa48a28d83bd8f434348607368e52644febf'
].map(function(hex){
return new Buffer(hex, 'hex');
});


var redeemScript = bitcoin.script.multisig.output.encode(2, pubKeys); // 2 of 3
var scriptPubkey = bitcoin.script.scriptHash.output.encode(bitcoin.crypto.hash160(redeemScript));
var address = bitcoin.address.fromOutputScript(scriptPubkey);
```

Now the address changed to

```
38tjRCFaQWQ269oGDpEkdxh5iPgxh7kvtB
```

How could this happen? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you run bitcoinjs-lib in `main-net mode` and it generates the human-readable address for main-net

bitcoin-cli you execute with `-testnet` parameter and got address for test-net

you can check that these hashes are the same:

https://testnet.smartbit.com.au/tx/8c67e4d3264696d222d5a72c70c8806eb3f12b9a02d1bc80554ab00803be86c0

https://blockchain.info/address/38tjRCFaQWQ269oGDpEkdxh5iPgxh7kvtB

both are **4f0017ef9291b625bec1d7efacc246a37b293682**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputations. Thanks again.